# Continuously Appending Pandas data as row on console and displaying it on terminal/Console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having 10 CSV  files each of the CSV file is having same number of column from which I'm reading data one by one in the form of pandas data frame. I want those data to be displayed on console/Terminal in some table form. And it should be like if every time the data gets into new row. Any suggestions on this ?

Below is my sample CSV file :
[image]

Like this, there are 10 or more CSV file and I will be reading data from those file one by one and want to display on Console/Terminal.

**Brief Introduction to my Application**

I have a machine that is generating CSV files after a certain interval of time into a folder. I am using Watchdog library to put a watch on the folder where the CSV files are being generated. When I receive a CSV file I Read it into a pandas data frame. Sample CSV file is given above.

As far as the machine is running it will keep generating the CSV files. So if I want to see the data I need to open each and every CSV files, Instead, I want a View in which the Data gets updated when there is a new CSV file generated.

So Technically One CSV file is getting read gets converted into a data frame and then printed on Console/Terminal. And this process happens again when a new CSV file is generated, But when new data frame arrives, It should not overwrite the whole console, Instead it appends to the existing data on console.

Here is my main file :

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
import pandas as pd
from Append_Function import append_df_to_excel
import os.path
import sys

class Watcher:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.watch_dir = os.getcwd()
        print(args[0])
        self.directory_to_watch = os.path.join(self.watch_dir, args[1])
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.event_handler = Handler(patterns=["*.CSV"], ignore_patterns=["*.tmp"], ignore_directories=True)

    def run(self):
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.directory_to_watch, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)
            df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1, index_col=0)
            append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "myfile.xlsx"), df)
        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Taken any actionc here when a file is modified.
            df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0, index_col=0)
            append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "myfile.xlsx"), df)
            print("Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv)
    w = Watcher(sys.argv)
    w.run()
```

Here is my Append Function:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as ox


def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                       truncate_sheet=False,
                       **to_excel_kwargs):
    # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed

    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

    # Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist
    try:
        FileNotFoundError
    except NameError:
        FileNotFoundError = IOError

    try:
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = ox.load_workbook(filename,keep_vba=True)

        # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
        # if it was not specified explicitly
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

        # truncate sheet
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            # index of [sheet_name] sheet
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            # remove [sheet_name]
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # file does not exist yet, we will create it
        pass

    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 0

    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs, header=True)

    # save the workbook
    writer.save()
```

Comment: @coldspeed More Information Added with Code